# Should i be having console log on production front end

Tags: error-handling, frontend, console.log

Just curious so in any front end frameworks react/angular, you might import scripts like google or facebook. during such social media initialization, there might be errors,

would you want to console log out these errors ? if so, should you remove them on production ?
or else how would you want to log these errors ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Its a bad Practice** You should not have console.log() in the Production build.

> For application maintenance purpose you can send the **Error logs**
>   to the server, and you can identify the error logs.